# Why does Web Inspector show User Agent Stylesheet as 'locked'

Tags: safari, web-inspector, safari-web-inspector

I think the easiest way to show this is with a picture:

http://oi61.tinypic.com/r2s4f9.jpg

In Web Inspector, I'm trying to change display:block but it's 'locked'. Further, I can't figure out where this is coming from in my source code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shows as locked because you are not able to edit it directly using DevTools. You have to override the styles in the user agent stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Safari Web Inspector and check the Logs, and beware of any browser extensions or content blockers (iOS) you are using which can modify or inject content into a webpage.

The culprit in my case turned out to be a Content Blocker (iOS ad-blocker) which was blocking elements on the page by forcing a User Stylesheet to `display:none` on certain CSS elements. Because of this, Safari showed it as "locked" like in your screenshot with no way to edit/modify it. A warning appeared in the Web Inspector 'Logs' tab telling me that the content blocker prevented a frame from loading a resource.

Disabling the content blocker removed the forced stylesheet, and fixed the problem in my case.